# Why has c+tab quit starting a comment for me in Emmet?

Tags: sublimetext, emmet

I use comments a lot in HTML and it used to be that when using Sublime Text with Emmet if i typed the c key and then the tab key i got the start of an HTML comment, now intead I am getting a center element.
Why would this have changed and how might I get back the other behaviour with is the one I want?

Comment: As you can see [in the source](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json#L683), c is still used for comments. You likely have a conflict with another HTML package. Unfortunately, the only way to find out which package might override this, is trial and error — by disabling all packages in question.

Comment: yeah, turned out it was the package called better complete